# How to write to firestore emulator?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am developing a firebase cloud function that writes to a firestore database.

During development I want the function to write to a local database. So I've started a firestore emulator. But the data is still written to the actual database.

How can I configure the cloud functions to use the local database?

This is my setup:

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as cors from "cors";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

const REGION = "europe-west1";
const COLLECTION_CONTACT_FORM = "contact_form";

const serviceAccount = require("../keys/auth-key.json");
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

const corsMiddleware = cors({origin: true});

export const sendContactForm = functions.region(REGION).https.onRequest((request, response) => corsMiddleware(request, response, async () => {
    let {text} = request.body;
    let result = await admin.firestore().collection(COLLECTION_CONTACT_FORM).add({text});
    response.send((result.id));
}));
```

This is the console output when starting the emulator:

```
[1] i  firestore: Serving WebChannel traffic on at http://localhost:8081
[1] i  firestore: Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
[1] ✔  functions: Emulator started at http://localhost:5000
[1] ✔  firestore: Emulator started at http://localhost:8080
[1] i  functions: Watching "path/functions" for Cloud Functions...
[1] ⚠  functions: Your GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable points to path/keys/auth-key.json. Non-emulated services will access production using these credentials. Be careful!
[1] ✔  functions[sendContactForm]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5000/project/europe-west1/sendContactForm).
```

When triggering the local endpoint, the production database is written to.

Answer (score 2):

The firestore admin `initializeApp()` will correctly handle switching between local emulator and production database depending on where it is running. So if you simply remove the service account credentials it should work properly:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as cors from "cors";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

const REGION = "europe-west1";
const COLLECTION_CONTACT_FORM = "contact_form";

admin.initializeApp();
const corsMiddleware = cors({origin: true});

export const sendContactForm = functions.region(REGION).https.onRequest((request, response) => corsMiddleware(request, response, async () => {
    let {text} = request.body;
    let result = await admin.firestore().collection(COLLECTION_CONTACT_FORM).add({text});
    response.send((result.id));
}));
```

But if for some reason you're trying to write to a firestore database outside of the one that the project is created in, you can use firestore/grpc separately from the firebase classes and then use the environment to either include your service account credentials or location emulator credentials. A local emulator example:

```
const {Firestore} = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const {credentials} = require('@grpc/grpc-js');

const db = new Firestore({
  projectId: 'my-project-id',
  servicePath: 'localhost',
  port: 5100,
  sslCreds: credentials.createInsecure(),
  customHeaders: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer owner"
  }
});

await db.collection("mycollection").doc("someid").set({ test: "value" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Same answer, but with the `docId` set dynamically.

```js
exports.makeUppercase = functions.firestore.document('Messages/{docId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const original = snap.data().original;
    functions.logger.log('Uppercasing', context.params.docId, original);
    const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
    // return snap.ref.set({ uppercase }, { merge: true });
    return admin.firestore().collection('AnotherCollection').doc(context.params.docId).set({ uppercase }, { merge: true });
});
```

This grabs the `docId` that was set dynamically and uses it to write to a document with the same name but in a different collection.

Also I left in commented code for writing to the same document in the same collection. Beware that using `onUpdate` or `onWrite` instead of `onCreate` makes an infinite loop as each write triggers the function again!